# Copying a file to mapped drive not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to connect to a network drive, copy a file and move it to another location, and log if it is successful or not. This is what I got so far:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

if exist Transfer_logfile.txt (
    ECHO Y | del Transfer_logfile.txt
)

set LogFile=_logfile.txt
set logg=^> _^&^& type _^&^&type _^>^>%LogFile%


for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (ipaddresses.txt) do (

    net use \\%%A\c$\test  /USER:test %logg%
    echo copying files across to %%A... %logg%
    COPY -f -R -Y C:\test\test.exe \\%%A\c$\test\test.exe %logg%
    echo Copy completed.. %logg%
    net use \\%%A\c$\test /delete /Y %logg%
)

pause
```

Any help on how to finish this of would be appreciated.

I am struggling to save any errors in the output. If it errors I want it to just save that it failed in output and go on to the next IP in the IP address text file.

I think, I need to wrap an if around the net use checking that the ip address pings first. However this does not work.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

if exist Transfer_logfile.txt (
    ECHO Y | del Transfer_logfile.txt
)

set LogFile=_logfile.txt
set logg=^> _^&^& type _^&^&type _^>^>%LogFile%

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (ipaddresses.txt) do (

ping -n %%A > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo
ELSE goto :skipcopyhost1
net use \\%%A\c$\test  %logg%
echo copying files across to %%A... %logg%

COPY -f -R -Y C:\test\test.exe \\%%A\c$\test\test.exe %logg%
echo Copy completed.. %logg%

net use \\%%A\c$\test /delete /Y %logg%
)

pause
```

Comment: what du you expect the content of logg to represent? also, your copy flags are not windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this not tested batch code:

```
@echo off
if not exist ipaddresses.txt goto :EOF
setlocal
del /F Transfer_logfile.txt 2>nul
set "LogFile=Transfer_logfile.txt"

for /F %%A in (ipaddresses.txt) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n %%A >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%A is not available in network.>>%LogFile%
    ) else (
        echo Connecting to %%A ...>>%LogFile%
        %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use X: \\%%A\c$\test /persistent:no /Y 2>&1 >>%LogFile%
        echo Copying file to %%A ...>>%LogFile%
        copy /B /V /Y C:\test\test.exe X:\test.exe 2>&1 >>%LogFile%
        echo Disconnecting from %%A ...>>%LogFile%
        %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use X: /delete /Y 2>&1 >>%LogFile%
    )
    echo.>>%LogFile%
)
endlocal
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `net /?`
- `net use /?`
- `set /?`

Further read the Microsoft articles:

- [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)
- [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576)

I don't explain all the errors in your code as they are too many.